# Error: Missing newline after argument, │ An argument definition must end with a newline

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am running a docker container to build python packages. I am using the null_resource and `local-exec` for doing this as shown below:

```
resource "null_resource" "install_dependencies" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "docker run -v (dirname "{PWD}"):/var/task 'public.ecr.aws/sam/build-${local.python_runtime}' /bin/sh -c 'pip install -r ${var.package_requirements_path} -t ${var.lambda_function_source_directory};exit'"
  }

  triggers = {
    dependencies_versions = filemd5(var.package_requirements_path)
  }
}
```

However, I get `│ An argument definition must end with a newline.` My question is, what does this error mean?

Comment: I don't think `PWD` will work like that.

Comment: I'm unable to test at the moment, but I think 1 problem is your quotes. You have double quotes within double quotes & terraform usually throws that type of error when your cmd syntax is incorrect or improperly quoted. An easy way to test is to change your command = "" into something really simple. If the error goes away, you know you need to fix your command line.

Comment: you mean that should be `${PWD}`?

Comment: @paulg, should I use tripple quotes for the inner quote? It's one challenge I faced cos I didnt know how to get around that.

Comment: @theSekyi - you could try just `${PWD}` as mentioned fixing with back slashes. `\"{PWD}\"`

Comment: @paulg `command = "docker run -v (dirname ${PWD}):/var/task 'public.ecr.aws/sam/build-${local.python_runtime}' /bin/sh -c 'pip install -r ${var.package_requirements_path} -t ${var.lambda_function_source_directory};exit'"` also gives `│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.` error

Comment: Yes, that way it's trying to reference a variable/data source/attribute from a resource. Try using `$${PWD}` so the literal `${PWD}` is preserved.

Comment: @MarkoE, that also throws an error - `Error running command 'docker run -v (dirname ${PWD}):/var/task 'public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.8' /bin/sh -c 'pip install -r ../lambda_functions/es_index_to_s3/requirements.txt -t ../lambda_functions/es_index_to_s3/;exit'': exit status
│ 2. Output: /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
│ /bin/sh: -c: line 0: `docker run -v (dirname ${PWD}):/var/task 'public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.8' /bin/sh -c 'pip install -r ../lambda_functions/es_index_to_s3/requirements.txt -t ../lambda_functions/es_index_to_s3/;exit''`

Comment: Well, the error seems to have moved to the `/bin/sh` part of the command as you can see from the error. I think the issue here is that you cannot use relative paths. Are the Lambda functions one directory up compared to where you are running terraform from?

Comment: yes they are in the parent directory

Comment: Try using something like `'pip install -r ${path.root}/../lambda_functions/es_index_to_s3/requirements.txt -t ${path.root}/../lambda_functions/es_index_to_s3/`.

Comment: @MarkoE, thanks. I resolved it by moving everything to a script and calling the script.

Answer (score -1):

It fixed after running formatting on it.
`fmt`

I use PyCharm so I run formatting using IDE.

Comment: This answer is not very helpful. Could you diff the files before and after and then let us know what the differences were?